# Stripe payment gateway for app store application

Tags: ios, iphone, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

I have faced to a problem during publication of my app.

Does anyone know how do Fiverr or similar companies do that to get out of the apple payment system? I mean they are not using the APS because of the 30% high charge fee.(Are they?)

How could makes it happen?

Comment: In short, you can use an external/other payment method if your selling stuff  that's consumed outside the app. Please read [The Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/).

Answer (score 0):

As per the apple guide line for the physical good purchase you need to use third party payment gateway like PayPal, Strip etc.

For the digital goods you need to use Apple In-App purchase.

There is some workaround if you don't want to use the digital payment without Apple In-App Purchase. You need to keep payment related stuff in your website for that.

Hope this help.

Comment: Apple also allows an other payment method, if the value is the same or worse as what's offered in the app. Only then you're allowed to have a link to the payment website in your app.

Comment: We are selling contents. Can u please explain your last quote more?

Comment: @PatrikCsík Just read Apples guidelines yourself, that'll save you some time